# Where in Query with Array in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have array number = {2,3,4,5,6}

Now i have to select rows from table "dtlRecord" where this number is a column.

```
Number count
2      10
3      23
4      20
```

So what i need is

```
select sum(count) from dtlRecord where number in (2,3,4,5,6) group by number
```

I need above query in LINQ to SQL

Comment: This will cover the IN part:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857973

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just using inner join:

```
int[] numbers = new[] { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

from r in dtlRecord
join number in numbers on r.Number equals number
group r by r.Number into g
        select new {
            Number = g.Key,
            Sum = g.Sum(r => r.Count)
        };
```

or

```
dtlRecord
    .Join(numbers, r => r.Number, number => number, (r, number) => new {r, number})
    .GroupBy(arg => arg.r.Number, arg => arg.r)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Number = g.Key,
        Sum = g.Sum(r => r.Count)
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Enumerable.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880.aspx):

```
int[] numbers = new[] { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
var query = from r in dtlRecords
            where numbers.Contains(r.Number)
            group r by r.Number into g
            select new {
                Number = g.Key,
                Sum = g.Sum(r => r.Count)
            };

foreach(var result in query) {
    Console.WriteLine("Number = {0}, Sum = {1}", result.Number, result.Sum);
}
```

Comment: +1 because my answer appeared to confuse the OP.  Maybe he'll have better luck with your example.

Answer (score 1):

**LINQ Equivalent Of Where IN** 
http://www.onedotnetway.com/linq-equivalent-of-where-in/

Comment: my number column are Guid datatype and when i execute query in Linqpad, it says Could not format node 'New' for execution as SQL

Comment: If your column is guid, why does your example show int numbers?

Comment: just wanted to give simple example

Comment: Check out Jason's example and substitute a guid array for the numeric array.