# How to implement SQL "in" in Entity framework 4.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How to implement following query of SQL in entity framework. 
`SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserID in (1,2,3,4)`.

I am trying to do

```
var users = from e in context.Users where e.UserId in (list of user ids)
```

Thanks
Ashwani

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linq to Entities - Sql "IN" clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857973/linq-to-entities-sql-in-clause)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var users = from e in context.Users where idList.Contains(e.UserId)
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
var identifiers = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
var users = from e in context.Users where identifiers.Contains(e.UserId);
```