# LINQ to Entities - Where IN clause in query

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Linq to Entities - Sql “IN” clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857973/linq-to-entities-sql-in-clause)
>   [How to implement SQL “in” in Entity framework 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973755/how-to-implement-sql-in-in-entity-framework-4-0)

how can I add WHERE IN statement like...

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ID IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

in entity framework

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Use `Contains`:

```
int[] ids = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

var query = db.myTable.Where(item => ids.Contains(item.ID));
```

or in query syntax:

```
int[] ids = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

var query = from item in db.myTable
            where ids.Contains(item.ID)
            select item;
```

Comment: @Jon Skeet thanks. But I have question. I believe you can solve that. That is when ids is being fetching from another table schema and contains some millions data then I can not make this faster. It is being slower for comparison. Is it my thinking or the compiler is giving best optimize run time by managing internal indexing/some other complex algorithm? Please response , I need it now.

Comment: @MuhammadAshikuzzaman: In that case you should be doing it with a join instead.

Comment: Another thing is that if ids is another model list then I can not use .Contains function what is the way to check .Contains in lambda expression? thanks :)

Comment: @MuhammadAshikuzzaman: At this point you should really be asking another question with all the relevant details. (Again, that sounds like you should be using a join...)

Comment: Thanks. Here I have make a question. Please see. [.Contains Problem](http://goo.gl/9bc7JF)

Answer (score 3):

I think answer lies somewhere along these lines...

```
Array a = {1,2,3,4,5}

...WHERE a.Contains(ID)
```

Comment: and of course, Jon Skeet gives the best answer. And he's FIRST! I wonder how he does it, really. :-)