# What is the difference between INTERSECT and WHERE IN?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have written and passed 70-433 (SQL 2008 MCTS exam) and was reviewing when I realised that I have been doing what `INTERSECT` does with a `WHERE IN` subquery, as well as `EXCEPT` with a `WHERE NOT IN` subquery.

Are there any differences between using the new commands instead of subqueries?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`INTERSECT` and `EXCEPT` compare all the selected values in the rows returned while `WHERE IN` and `WHERE NOT IN` only compare one column at a time.

```
SELECT name,date from customers
EXCEPT
SELECT name, date from orders
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir. You are a gentleman and a sql wiz. 
Thumbs up.

Answer (score 4):

There is an important difference in how they handle `NULL`s

```
WITH T1 AS(SELECT 1 AS COL UNION SELECT NULL),
     T2 AS (SELECT 2 AS COL UNION SELECT NULL)
SELECT * FROM T1 
INTERSECT 
SELECT * FROM T2;
```

.

```
COL
-----------
NULL

(1 row(s) affected)
```

.

```
WITH T1 AS(SELECT 1 AS COL UNION SELECT NULL),
     T2 AS (SELECT 2 AS COL UNION SELECT NULL)
SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE COL IN (SELECT COL FROM T2) ;
```

.

```
COL
-----------

(0 row(s) affected)
```

.

```
WITH T1 AS(SELECT 1 AS COL UNION SELECT NULL),
     T2 AS (SELECT 2 AS COL UNION SELECT NULL)
SELECT * FROM T1 
EXCEPT 
SELECT * FROM T2;
```

.

```
COL
-----------
1

(1 row(s) affected)
```

.

```
WITH T1 AS(SELECT 1 AS COL UNION SELECT NULL),
     T2 AS (SELECT 2 AS COL UNION SELECT NULL)
SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE COL NOT IN (SELECT COL FROM T2);
```

.

```
COL
-----------

(0 row(s) affected)
```