# Get random users

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a list of user ids and want to get a few random users from a database which doesn't contain users from my list using LINQ-SQL.

For example:

```
//it's user ids 
var existsUsers = new[]{1,2,3,4}

// I want to implement this function:
List<User> users = GetRandomUsers(randomUsersCount, existsUsers)
```

Comment: And what is your question? What have you tried / done / achieved until now? What's the data model you want to access?

Comment: I think the question is pretty clear. He wants to know how to do something like `allUsers.Except(existsUsers).Shuffle().Take(randomUsersCount)` in linq-to-sql.

Comment: It is not clear whether he has problems with some specific part of it or he wants us to write the entire code.

Comment: See: [Random row from Linq to Sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648196/random-row-from-linq-to-sql)

Comment: @Tomas Narros: Data model is just User{int id, varchar Name}. I can get ALL users and then filter them. But i think  it's not good because of perfomance problems.

Comment: @Ani Thanks but that code just get a random users. I want to get random users with some conditions.

Comment: How large is your exception list compared to the total number of users in the db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you just can do an 
[Linq In Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857973/linq-to-entities-sql-in-clause) since you have the ids already.

```
//Not tested.... may have syntax errors.
GetRandomUsers(randomUsersCount, existsUsers)
{
     var users= (from u in users
                where existsUsers.Contains(u.Id)
                select u).Take(randomUserCount);

     return users;

}
```

Comment: ohhh thanks. I really stupid. I thinked that i cannt use local collection in linq2sql queries.

Comment: Don't feel stupid... the syntax is a little odd (backwards when compared to regular SQL).