# Select "IN" in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I get a list of entities to update and I have their ids. I want to get the original ones from the database, so I do:

```
String[] ids = updatedEvents.Select(ue => ue.id).ToArray();

var originalEventsToUpdate = Db.tbl_ffk_event
                               .Where(e => ids.Contains(e.id))
                               .ToArray();
```

But what I get using the log is this generated SQL:

```
SELECT [t0].[id], [t0].[fs_mapping_id], [t0].[fs_id_value], [t0].[desc]
FROM [dbo].[tbl_ffk_event] AS [t0]
WHERE 0 = 1
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.0.30319.1
```

And that SQL means "get the whole table".

How can I generate a "IN" like this:

```
SELECT [t0].[id], [t0].[fs_mapping_id], [t0].[fs_id_value], [t0].[desc]
FROM [dbo].[tbl_ffk_event] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[id] IN ('aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd','eee',)
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I feel stupid, I didn't see the `WHERE 0 = 1`. It's because at that point, there where nothing in the `ids` collection. I have checked out now ensuring there are items, and the SQL is generated correctly. Sorry.

Comment: You said, "And that SQL means 'get the whole table'." I think you meant, 'Get nothing'. That WHERE clause is always false.

Comment: Are your ID's indeed strings?

Comment: I thought it says 'WHERE 1 = 1' I didn't realize that.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857973/linq-to-entities-sql-in-clause

Comment: @Catcall, duplicate how?

Comment: vtortola, I wouldn't feel stupid over that one, since the format of the SQL is (while correct for what it has to do) somewhat unexpected. It's sensible enough SQL I suppose though, considering that `WHERE [t0].[id] IN ()` would be invalid. Clever ol' linq ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, due to the clause `WHERE 0 = 1` this SQL will return an empty recordset (i.e. correctly mapped in terms of the schema, but with no rows).

The code you give seems correct, but something has convinced the query provider that there can never be a matching row.

Assuming it's not correct in this, I'd look at the column mapping for the `id` property. Does it match that of the database correctly?

Comment: I thought it says 'WHERE 1 = 1' I didn't realize that.

Comment: What about the mapping, did it reveal the problem as I suspected (if not, maybe add it to your question).

Answer (score 0):

Probably your list is coming empty, this is the normal behavior of Linq.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim strval As String = ""
Dim strnum(30) As String

strval = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9"

strnum = strval.split(",")

originalEventsToUpdate = (from a in Db.tbl_ffk_event where strnum.contains(a.id) select a).tolist
```

Comment: FYI: This code is VB.NET, not C# as in the question. (Does VB even have LINQ? I honestly don't know.)

Comment: I think they added LINQ to vb on Tuesday