# LINQ to Entities Qyery Syntax: "IN" set operations

Tags: sql, linq, syntax, entities

In SQL, you could write a query such as:

```
SELECT NAME, QUOTA, SALES FROM SALESREPS
WHERE REP_OFFICE IN (11, 13, 52);
```

How would can I construct a IN set operation within LINQ?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857973/linq-to-entities-sql-in-clause][1]

Check this link to find the answer to your question.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this link: [101 LINQ Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746) Should answer this question and any others you run into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume we're talking LINQ to Objects here:

```
var x = from s in SalesReps 
        where new[] { 11, 13, 52 }.Contains(s.RepOffice) 
        select s;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] nums = new { 11, 13, 52 };
IEnumerable<SalesRep> salesReps = 
    MyEntities.SalesReps.Where(s => nums.Contains(s.Rep_Office));
```