# linq how to select a parent with a child collection that contains one or many of an array (or list) of values

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections

This seems like it would be easy enough

```
var orx = gg.Where(x=>x.ProductAttributes.Any (pa =>pa.AttributeId == "home"));
```

returns gg when product attributes has a value of "home"

I need it to return where and gg has product attribute values from an array
i.e.

```
var orx = gg.Where(x=>x.ProductAttributes.Any (pa =>pa.AttributeId in "home,work"));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linq to Entities - Sql "IN" clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857973/linq-to-entities-sql-in-clause)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

what about...

```
string[] values = new string[] { "home", "work" };
var orx = gg.Where(x => x.ProductAttributes.Any(pa => values.Contains(pa.AttributeId));
```

or even `"home,work".Contains(pa.AttributeId)` should work, if your list is as reliable as your example. (I by no mean recommend this unless you can ensure that AttributeId will not be a substring of any of the list words.. such as "me")

Comment: `"home,work".Contains(pa.AttributeId)` will return wrong result if any of AttributeIds will be a part of `home` or `work` words, for instance `ork`...

Comment: @sll: Yes, which is why I said "if your list is as reliable as your example"

Comment: That was the syntax I was missing, had it backwards

Answer (score 5):

Using [Enumerable.Contains()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880.aspx):

```
var orx = gg.Where(x => x.ProductAttributes
                        .Any(pa =>
                             array.Containspa(pa.AttributeId));

var orx = gg.Where(x => x.ProductAttributes
                        .Any(pa =>
                             "home, work".Split(',').Contains(pa.AttributeId));
```