# filter a linq query based on the results of another query's results

Tags: c#, linq

I am wanting to filter a linq query

I have 2 linq statements

The 1st gets all the stores I want and the 2nd is where I filter information based on the results found in the 1st query.

```
var stores = ctx.Stores.Where(ps => ps.ParentStoreID == parent.ParentStoreID && ps.StoreID!=storeID);

var query = (from a in ctx.TransactionTable
          from b in ctx.MappingTable.Where(x => x.TransactionId== a.TransactionId).DefaultIfEmpty()
             where a.StoreID!=storeID
                 select new
                           {
                              Transactions = a,
                              Mapping = b
                           }).ToList();
```

How do I add another where clause into my 2nd query to only return results where a.StoreId is contained within the stores result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
var stores = ctx.Stores.Where(ps => ps.ParentStoreID == parent.ParentStoreID && ps.StoreID!=storeID);

var query = (from a in ctx.TransactionTable
            from b in ctx.MappingTable.Where(x => x.TransactionId==a.TransactionId).DefaultIfEmpty()
            where a.StoreID!=storeID && stores.Select(s => s.StoreID).Contains(a.StoreID)
            select new
            {
                Transactions = a,
                Mapping = b
            }).ToList();
```

You can find more info here:
[Linq to Entities - SQL "IN" clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857973/linq-to-entities-sql-in-clause)

Comment: Instead of `stores.Select(s => s.StoreID).Contains(a.StoreID)` you can also write the shorter `stores.Any(s => s.StoreID == a.StoreID)`. I believe the translation to SQL will be the same either way.

Comment: Thanks David. I was missing the stores.Select(s=>s.StoreId) before trying the contains.