# How to query entities from a collection without using foreach

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I've been struggling and trying to get my mind wrapped around these concepts. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Given a collection of Orders in one table what is the best way to iterate over it, and perform queries against other tables.

This loop does what I want, but I've been told and shown how this causes performance problems. On other posts I've read where it is best to query the dbase outside of loops.

```
foreach (var item in myOrders)
{
var lookUpValues=(from f in ORDERS
where f.ORDERS ==item.ORDER_ID 
&& f.ORDERS_SUFFIX==item.LINE
select f.Something);
}
```

Rather than pulling down the entire Order table prior to iterating over I've tried something like this, but as you see it won't return the accurate rows.

```
var orderIds=myOrders.Select (x =>x.ORDER_ID).Distinct().ToList();
var lineIds=myOrders.Select (x =>x.LINE).Distinct().ToList();

var query=(from f in ORDERS
where orderIds.Contains(f.ORDERS)
&& lineIds.Contains(f.ORDERS_SUFFIX)
select f).ToList();
```

The below would do what I think is needed. It would return the correct Orders that are required to iterate over. However, it throws an error, which I believe is because you can't query memory objects and entities together.

```
var ordersAndLine=(from f in myOrders select new{sId=f.ORDER_ID,line=f.LINE}).ToList();

var query=(from f in ORDERS
from s in ordersAndLine
where s.sId==f.ORDERS
&& s.line==f.ORDERS_SUFFIX
select f).ToList();
```

NotSupportedException: Unable to create a constant value of type 'Anonymous type'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

I really hope my question makes sense. I apologize in advance if I didn't explain my situation correctly. What I've been doing is pulling down much of the table to memory to iterate over, but I was concerned that this would cause performance issues and wanted to see if there is a better way to filter the result query.

Comment: Where do the myOrders and the ORDERS come from.  Are they properties from a data context?  Are they collections that you have already pulled back?  I am guessing that ORDERS is a property on a data context and myOrders is the result of a previous query, but it isn't easy to tell.  Furthermore, if myOrders (or orders) is the result of a query, is it still an IQueryable, or have you called ToArray or ToList?

Comment: Hi Devin. Orders is a Table and myOrders is a user defined subset of Orders that exist in a temp table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you combine your first attempt and your last attempt you'd have it. The last attempt would be fine if you weren't creating an anonymous type.

```
var ordersAndLine=(from f in myOrders select f).ToList();

var query=(from f in ORDERS
from s in ordersAndLine
where s.ORDER_ID==f.ORDERS
&& s.LINE==f.ORDERS_SUFFIX
select f).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi Kirk, I don't have the code in front of me now. But I think it throws an error  since ORDERS is a table entity where as ordersAndLine is in memory. Error message posted above.

Comment: I think I got what your saying though. Give me a few minutes to try this. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/095745fe-dcf0-4142-b684-b7e4a1ab59f0/

[Linq to Entities - SQL "IN" clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857973/linq-to-entities-sql-in-clause)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var orders = myOrders.SelectMany(item => (from f in ORDERS
                                          where f.ORDERS ==item.ORDER_ID 
                                          && f.ORDERS_SUFFIX==item.LINE
                                          select f.Something));
```