# Typed Datatable - find int array using linq

Tags: c#, linq

How do I query a typed datatable using linq to see it contains any number of the defined array.

```
string[] arInts = {1, 2, 3};
```

I wanted to query the table and find if it contains any number in array **arInts**

Comment: [Linq to Entities - Sql "IN" clause][1]
oh my god,It's very good.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857973/linq-to-entities-sql-in-clause

Comment: What does it mean "Typed datatable"?

Comment: @hughstone to put a URL in a comment you do it like: [ text ] ( url )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like the question here:

[Linq to Entities - SQL "IN" clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857973/linq-to-entities-sql-in-clause)
The following query should work:

```
var q = from t in tableName
               where arInts.Contains(t.fieldName)
               select t;
```