# SQL TO LINQ Where In Clause with Max

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I want to convert the following query to LINQ equivalent. I've  gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16555471/convert-sql-to-linq-to-entities-where-in-clause) but unable to acheive my results which has Max. can anyone help me in this regard.

Below is my SQL Query:

```
select max(a.amount_limit) as AmountLimit from tbl_AmountEmpRole a where a.Role_Name in(select b.Role_name from tbl_UserRoles b where Emp_id=4)
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you show your current linq code, even if it does not use `max` yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a variable called `context`, this should work:

```
context.tbl_AmountEmpRole
.Where(er => context.tbl_UserRoles.Where(ur => ur.Emp_id == 4).Select(ur => ur.Role_Name).Contains(er.Role_Name))
.Max(er => er.amount_limit);
```

However, I believe you might be able to rewrite your query using a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT MAX(a.amount_limit) as AmountLimit FROM tbl_AmountEmpRole a 
INNER JOIN tbl_UserRoles b 
ON a.Role_Name = b.Role_Name
WHERE b.Emp_id = 4
```

In which case you could use the `Join` method:

```
context.tbl_AmountEmpRole.Join(context.tbl_UserRoles, er => er.Role_Name, ur => ur.Role_Name, new { er, ur })
.Where(j => j.ur.Emp_id = 4)
.Max(j => j.er.amount_limit);
```

Make sure to double-check syntax and signatures. I wrote this from memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can try somthing like this :

```
 var role_names=tbl_UserRoles.Where(x=> x.Emp_id==4).Select(x=>x.Role_name);
 var MaxacountLimit=tbl_AmountEmpRole.Where(y=>role_names.contains(y))
 .Max(z=>z.amount_limit);
```