# IN query condition with Entity Framework

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework

Does Entity Framework provide a way to use `in` as a `where` condition?

I'd like to use LINQ if possible to generate a query equivalent to:

```
select * from dbo.Strains where Name in ('A', 'B', 'C',  … )
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linq to Entities - Sql "IN" clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857973/linq-to-entities-sql-in-clause)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var result = context.Strains
    .Where(s => new[] { "A", "B", "C" }.Contains(s.Name));
```

Entity Framework is smart enough to translate this into the appropriate SQL.