# 'IN' clause in linq

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a table name "actorlist" with column 'id' and 'ActorName' which contain 50 numbers of rows and also I have another table name "addrecord" with column 'iid','Actor1','Actor2','Actor3','Actor4'.  'id' column in "actorlist" and 'iid' column in "addrecord" are not same.

I have to find all those 'ActorName' from "actorlist" which are not in 'Actor1','Actor2','Actor3','Actor4' column. What will be LInq query for this result? Note that "addrecord" table have only one row.

please help me.....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linq to Entities - Sql "IN" clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857973/linq-to-entities-sql-in-clause)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible LINQ to get what you described in question (method syntax) :

```
DataContext.actorlists
           .Select(o => o.ActorName)
           .Where(o => !DataContext
                             .addrecords
                             .Any(p => p.Actor1 == o.ActorName ||
                                       p.Actor2 == o.ActorName ||
                                       p.Actor3 == o.ActorName ||
                                       p.Actor4 == o.ActorName))
```

or if you prefer query syntax, you can try this :

```
from a in DataContext.actorlists
where !(from b in DataContext.addrecords
        where b.Actor1 == a.ActorName
              || b.Actor2 == a.ActorName
              || b.Actor3 == a.ActorName
              || b.Actor4 == a.ActorName).Any()
select a.ActorName
```

Comment: public static List<mainISRC> comedianlist(int iid)
        {
            List<mainISRC> newlst = new List<mainISRC>();
            ISRCManagementDBEntities1 dbcontext = new ISRCManagementDBEntities1();
            newlst=(from z in dbcontext.Comedians
                    where !(from b in dbcontext.mainISRCs 
                    where b.id==iid && b.Actor1==z.Comedian1 || b.Comedian1==z.Comedian1 || b.Comedian3==z.Comedian1 || b.Comedian4==z.Comedian1).Any()
                    select z.Comedian1).ToList();            
            return newlst;
        }

Comment: is showing error at .any() that "linq a query body must end with a select clause or a group clause" please have a check and hep me sir..