# use linq in operator

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, in-operator

I want In operator in mvc Linq.

like this sql (stud_ID is int, primary key and auto increment):

```
select * from student where stud_ID in (1,4,6,10,5);
```

how can I adapt for linq this sql?

like

```
List<int> nl = new List<int>();
nl.add(1);
nl.add(4);
nl.add(6);
nl.add(10);
nl.add(5);
List<student> students = db.student.where(a => a.stud_ID.In(nl)).toList();
//this code is fitting from my mind :D
```

or the other scenario

```
List<student> st = db.studentOrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(5); //only for create auto list student type
List<student> students = db.student.where(
    a => a.stud_ID.In(st.Select(b => b.stud_ID).toList())
).toList(); //again fitting
```

I can this

```
List<student> students = new List<student>();
foreach(var item in nl)
{
    students.add(db.student.where(a => a.stud_ID == item).First());
}
```

but I dont want to use for or foreach or do-while or while :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linq to Entities - Sql "IN" clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857973/linq-to-entities-sql-in-clause)

Comment: thanks for your answer. did I find but cant find. This answer work. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
List<student> students = db.student.where(a => nl.Contains(a.Stud_ID)).toList();
```

This checks, if the student ID is present in the List `nl`. If so, the student gets returned in the result.

Your second requirement is different, if I understand it correctly. You have two collections of studentes, and want to know which students are also in `st`.

```
var intersectedList = students.Intersect(st);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
List<student> students = db.student.Where<student>(a =>  nl.Contains(a.stud_ID)).ToList<student>();
```