# Getting the selected datalist by an array

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql

I am going to ask a very basic question and probably a repeated one but I have a bit different situation.
I want to use "in" operator in Linq.
I have to get all the rows from table which has Id provided 
by my array and returns the row if it has. How can I do it.

My array has

var aa="1091","1092","1093" and so on.

and my table uses these Ids as Primary keys 
.I have to get all the rows whose Id is contained in the array and I do not want to use S.P.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linq to Entities - Sql "IN" clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857973/linq-to-entities-sql-in-clause)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Enumerable.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb352880%28v=vs.100%29.aspx),

```
var aa = new string[3] { "1091", "1092", "1093" };
var res = yourDataSource.Where(c => aa.Contains(c.ID));
```

Comment: contains will not do the job here or it will also work in this case?

Answer (score 1):

`IN` statements are created by using `Contains` in your `Where` call. Assuming you use integers as IDs, you could write something like this:

```
var myArray=new[]{1091,1092,1094};
var myEntities=from entity in myTable
               where myArray.Contains(entity.ID)
               select entity;
```

Comment: Actually I am trying something like this::
var myEntities = from entity in ObjReport
                                     where RowArray.Contains(entity.ID.ToString())
                                     select entity;

Comment: I am getting null over this.

Comment: Actually my source in which I am searching the Records on basis of Id.Id is a int type but The Array in which I am getting the Id as strings, I am not able to get the desired results.

Comment: You can easily convert the strings to ints with int.Parse, eg `myStringIds.Select(s=>int.Parse(s)).ToArray()`. Adding the conversion in the LINQ statement is a bad idea because your provider may not know how to translate `ToString()` to a SQL statement. In L2S, it would try to load *everything* and then execute `ToString()` on each entity. In EF, it would flatly refuse with a compile error