# How to validate every value in a List in where Clause?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

The Title is a little bit complicating. 
The Question here is easy:

If got a CheckBoxList. In this List you are allowed to do multiple choice. I put every chosen value from the Checkboxlist into a list because i need it for my where clause. So i have:

```
List<int> queueIDList = new List<int>();
```

Short version of my LINQ:

```
var reports = from t in tickets 
              where t.queue_id == every value in queueIDList 
              select t.ticketnumber;
```

So how do i have to write it when i want every ticketnumber from DB which is the same like in the queueIDList?
For better knowing - in the CheckBoxList u can chose different Queues, at least u have to chose 1 (null is not allowed). I added the ID's of the chosen Queues to a list and now i want to have every ticketnumber from DB where the queueID equals with the values from the queueIDList.

I think the answer is easy but i'm really stuck with my mind.

Thanks for every help!

Comment: Think this article might be helpfull 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857973/linq-to-entities-sql-in-clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `Contains`:

```
var reports = from t in tickets 
          where queueIDList.Contains(t.queue_id)
          select t.ticketnumber;
```

Comment: thanks - like i said, it's too easy and i've tried it before but i didn't work because i wrote one letter wrong. Thank you!