# sql "not in" in Linq using datatable

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-entities

How to convert sql query to linq using datatable.

```
select DISTINCT targeturl from internal where TargetURL NOT in (select DISTINCT url from Internal)
```

using this query, but still not getting the correct result.

```
  var List1 = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(c => c.Field<string>("URL")).Distinct().ToList();
  var List2 = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(c => c.Field<string>("TargetURL")).Distinct().ToList();
  var Targetname = List2.Except(List1.ToList()).ToList();
```

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/q/857973/50447 - it should just be a case of adjusting the collection of items, and negating the where clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try populating an object then using the object to populate the datatable.

```
var data = Select(c => c.Field<string>("TargetURL")).Distinct().ToList();
Datatable dtMyTable = new Datatable();
dtMytable.Columns.Add("col1",typeof(string));
dtMytable.Columns.Add("col2",typeof(string));
dtMytable.Columns.Add("col3",typeof(string));
```

then populate the table

```
foreach (var item in data)
{
      dtMytable.Rows.Add(data.col1,data.col2,data.col3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to separate 
first

```
dim query = (from u in Internal select u.url).distinct
```

Second

```
dim tmp = (from t in Interal where not query.contains(TargetURL) select TargetURL ).ToList
```

It's in VB.net but You can translate easily
And you can too distinct with group by request.

Answer (score 0):

To write `SELECT DISTINCT targeturl from internal where TargetURL NOT in (select DISTINCT url from Internal)` in a linq lambda expression, you could use the following:

`var result = Internal
  .Select(a => a.TargetURL)
  .Where(a => !Internal.Select(i => i.url).Distinct().Contains(a.TargetURL));`

Or break it out a little as:

`var distinctUrls = Internal.Select(i => i.url).Distinct();
var result = Internal.Select(a => a.TargetUrl)
  .Where(a => !disctinctUrls.Contains(a.TargetUrl));`

The above creates an IEnumerable of urls, which we use as an exclusion in the where predicate.

Comment: How to use it with datatable?

Comment: I am using this way but still not getting the correct result.  var List1 = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(c => c.Field<string>("URL")).Distinct().ToList();
                    var List2 = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(c => c.Field<string>("TargetURL")).Distinct().ToList();
                    var Targetname = List2.Except(List1.ToList()).ToList();