# Sql IN Clause equivalent in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, compiler-errors, linq-to-entities

I want to use sql in cluase in linq for that i have tried contains but its showing error. My Code is..

```
 var allId = new int[] { 31, 32, 33 };
 var libraryList = from c in db.COURSELIBRARies
                   join cc in db.COURSECATEGORYTAGGINGs on c.LIBITEMID equals cc.COURSEID
                   where allId.Contains(cc.CATEGORYID) // here error is showing.
                   select new Library { Id = c.LIBITEMID, Name = c.GROUPNAME, Desc = c.DESCRIPTION, logo = c.LOGO, CategoryId = cc.CATEGORYID };
```

Error is :

> 'int[]' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload `'System.Linq.Queryable.Contains<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, TSource)'` has some invalid arguments
>
> Instance argument: cannot convert from `'int[]'` to `'System.Linq.IQueryable<int?>'`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linq to Entities - Sql "IN" clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857973/linq-to-entities-sql-in-clause)

Comment: Try changing the array `allId` into a List instead

Comment: That particular error is due to one of two things. Either you are lying and are not actually using `Entity Framework` but are instead using `Linq to SQL` or you are using `Entity Framework 2`, which does not support `IEnumerable.Contains`.

Comment: your first 3 lines of code doenst work. Splitting `{31,32,33}` with `.Split(',')` and the parsing the elements as `int` fails because `"{31" != int`

Comment: @JensKloster  by mistake i have written that actually its value coming dynamical and that is 31,32,33, so its working.

Answer (score 1):

Have you included;

```
using System.Linq;
```

?

Another possible cause would be that the value you are passing into Contains() is not an INT. Try casting it: `where allId.Contains((int)cc.CATEGORYID)`

Comment: what's the data type of cc.CATEGORYID? Maybe try casting it to an int?  where allId.Contains((int)cc.CATEGORYID)

Comment: What is the type of `cc.CATEGORYID`?