# Linq to Sql - return all data if 'contains' value is null in where clause

Tags: c#, asp.net, contains

I need to get all vendorname if value(data.vendorname) is null its give an error  Exception: "Value cannot be null."

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostFilter([FromBody] dynamic data)
{
    string[] vendorname = data.vendorname != null
                          ? data.vendorname.ToObject<string[]>()
                          : null;

    var items = (from s in context.AllInventories
                 where
                    (vendorname!=null
                     ? vendorname.Contains(s.VENDORNAME)
                     :1==1)
                 select s)
                 .Take(500)
                 .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Where do you get the exception? Are you sure data != null?

Comment: You can improve the elegance of your null checks with the C#6 null-propagator: `string[] vendorname = data?.vendorname?.ToObject<string[]>();`

Comment: @romanoza at select query its give an exception .
 
whenever vendorname is null its give an exception "Value cannot be null."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you simplify this, by just not applying any `where` at all if `vendorname` is null?

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostFilter([FromBody] dynamic data)
{
    string[] vendorname = data.vendorname != null
                          ? data.vendorname.ToObject<string[]>()
                          : null;

    var query = context.AllInventories.AsQueryable();
    if (vendorname != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(s => vendorname.Contains(s.VENDORNAME));
    }

    var items = query.Take(500).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Maybe instead of `query = context.AllInventories.Where(s => vendorname.Contains(s.VENDORNAME));` it could use `query = query.Where(s => vendorname.Contains(s.VENDORNAME));` to allow further query building (or if more query would be built upfront).

Comment: I think for multiple where clause condition it will not help me, because for that i need to mention multiple if condition which is not good solution.
any other solution?

Comment: Why is multiple if and multiple where not a good solution? Query is actually not executed until you call ToList or some other method that materializes data from database (or some other source).

Comment: @Jure, you are right, `query  = query.Where` was my intention anyway, thanks for the catch

Comment: @ArsalanK, quite contrary, this is a very good approach for multiple where's, because it allows you to keep only necessary conditions in the query, and smaller query may mean cleaner SQL code and faster execution

Comment: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<OrderApplication_2._0.Models.AllInventory>' to 'System.Data.Linq.Table<OrderApplication_2._0.Models.AllInventory>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
 
on this
query = query.Where(s => vendorname.Contains(s.VENDORNAME));

Comment: This is a bad way, because you are will fetsh all objects in the Db for a local join.

A much better way is to store the list of string in a temporary table, and do an in DB join and fetch the results. 
I'm used to large data sets, and this solution is not suitable for those at all

Comment: @user853710, well, there is no join here, and even if there were, it would still be possible to define join modifying `query`. The actual DB request won't happen until `ToList` is called, so this is not going to load more objects than required

Comment: Sure, but EF cannot do a in DB join with a local list. EF will fetch the entire table a do a in memory join, no matter if you call ToList or not. The Join here is represented by the contains method. It is even worse, since it is not a hashset but a list and the performance is even worse. It will load evrything

Comment: @user853710, LINQ converts `Contains` method to SQL `IN` clause. Here is [one reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857973/linq-to-entities-sql-in-clause), here is the [other](http://rob.conery.io/2008/02/27/creating-in-queries-with-linq-to-sql/). You can also run this by any SQL profiler to confirm. No memory joins

Comment: Since wehn. I checked it 5 min ago with EF5, EF6 and the profiler says to fetch the entire table. Still, even if were so, .... it would still be a bad way to do since it will still join with not indexed data. What ever you try, It is still not ass good as BulkSaving into a temp table and joining in the server. If you are talking about 10 record, well yes, but if you want scalability or you are joining 100s of records with milions of record in DB, you are running into a bottleneck.

Just because you can do something, it does not mean you should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a simple `if`-statement?

```
IEnumerable<Inventory> inventories = context.AllInventories;
if(vendorname != null)
    inventories = inventories.Where(i => vendorname.Contains(i.VENDORNAME));             
inventories = inventories.Take(500).ToList();
```

That's much better than hoping that your sql trick works and that the optimizer is clever enough to ignore   your pseudo-condition. It's also better to debug.

Comment: well i have multiple parameters along with vendorname, for this i need to mention mutliple if conditions. :/

Comment: @ArsalanK: still the best approach in terms of readability, maintainability, testability and performance.