# Array fo String to Use with IN CLAUSE in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to use string array in linq query with IN CLAUSE like below

```
    string[] strArray = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
    foreach (var item in SomeCollection.Where(x => x.column.Contains(seriesIIType)))
    {

    }
```

But I am getting below error.

> Error 1   The best overloaded method match for 'string.Contains(string)'
>   has some invalid arguments Error  2   Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   'string[]' to 'string'

Comment: what is `x.column`?

Comment: Try strArray.Contains

Comment: Because your question is unclear, and the code is not complete (and is probably incorrect too), then don't be surprised that all the answers are simply *guessing* what you want.

Comment: @sstan, I think my question very much clear as I just wanted to use IN clause with LINQ so no need to explain further about class model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the `Contains` method on your array.

```
string[] strArray = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
SomeCollection.Where(x => strArray.Contains(x.column))
```

This will return those items which has column property value is either one of those in the array.

Assuming `column` property is of same type as your array (`string`)

Comment: What if x.column = "ABC"?

Comment: Then it is not going to return that item. I don't think that is what the OP wanted. My answer was to fix the compiler error where he was not using the method properly.

Comment: @Steve I don't get your question still :)

Comment: @Shyju, x.column is type of string. And yes my compile time error has been fixed.

Comment: I was pointing to the fact that your answer is _An element of Array Contains Column_, while I had the impression that user wanted  _a Column Contains an element of Array_ but he has already made the choice between your answer an the one from rory.ap, so question closed.

Comment: I see. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me like you want to do this instead:

```
SomeCollection.Where(x => strArray.Any(y => x.column.Contains(y)));
```

But I don't know how `x.column.Contains` works because I don't know what `x.column` is.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be the other way around:

```
string[] seriesIIType = {"OC", "RH", "RC", "OA"};
foreach (var item in SomeCollection.Where(x => seriesIIType.Contains(x.Column)))
        {
        }
```

For reference: [Linq to Entities - SQL "IN" clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857973/linq-to-entities-sql-in-clause)

Is it very intuitive, isn't? but that's how it works in Linq world.