# SQL IN Query in LINQ With List

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

Need help in filtering LINQ select query with another `List<string>`

Like,

```
List<string> samplingList;

var Result = from F in db.TableA where F.flag == "A" && F.code in (samplingList)
```

`F.Code.Contains()` can accept only single value, How can I pass `samplingList` to LINQ to filter data. Basically I am looking for achieving SQL code  `value in ('V1', 'V2')` in LINQ.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linq to Entities - SQL "IN" clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857973/linq-to-entities-sql-in-clause)

Comment: You can execute a LINQ join on these two entities (TableA and samplingList).  Research that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```
samplingList.Contains(F.code)
```

So your complete query should be something like this:

```
var Result = from F in db.TableA where F.flag == "A" &&
             samplingList.Contains(F.code)
             select F;
```

Comment: This Solved the problem!  Thank you.