# Sentence Where in [...] ASP.net c# mvc Qlink

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I know how to do a where in Qlink... p.e.

```
public ActionResult Index(){
    using (DBEntities db = new DBEntities())
    {
        return View(db.vw_values.Where(m => m.value == 1).ToList());
    }
}
```

but I want to do a Where in but I´ve not found how to implement it... p.e.

```
... int[] values = {1,2,3, ...}
    return View(db.vw_values.Where(m => m.value == values).ToList()); ...
```

is it posible? (The idea, I know that this code is wrong)

Comment: `Where(m => values.Contains(m.value))`

Comment: Little bit of googling can save lot of time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linq to Entities - SQL "IN" clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857973/linq-to-entities-sql-in-clause)

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    using (DBEntities db = new DBEntities())
    {
        return View(db.vw_values.Where(m => values.Contains(m.value).ToList());
    }
}
```

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/getting-started-with-linq)
 you can learn more about LINQ in C# and all the other cool things you can do with it.