# Where IN Clause in Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework-core

I want to convert this SQL query to an Entity Framework Core 2.0 query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Product
WHERE ProdID IN (1,2,3);
```

Comment: ProdID column is of bigint type and contains only works with string columns

Comment: A question about Entity Framework Core 2.0 in 2018 is not a duplicate of a LINQ to Entities question from 2009.

Comment: @MarkRendle I suppose you're right...however the technique still applies. The underlying IQueryable implementation is what's different between various Linq-to-something technologies...making usage (fairly) consistent across the board.  Folks unfamiliar with the history of Linq may not realize this.

Comment: @KumudiniPorwal, `Contains` in Linq is a generic function taking a lambda as an argument...and can be of any type as inferred by the lambda itself.

Comment: @Clay sure but the linked answer is not what you would do using Marten, or NHibernate, or RavenDB. We shouldn't be linking EF Core to EF or Linq2Sql.

Comment: @Clay As you say, the SQL generation code for LINQ-to-Entities is completely different from EF Core's, so there's no reason to assume that the solution is the same. In search-ability terms, it would be better to have an answer to this EF Core question than the "Duplicate" flag.

Comment: I voted to reopen, given the collective concern. However, the point of Linq is that the *usage* is supposed to be identical across technologies...and I assume that's how the original duplicate flagger felt. So...to be clear, I'll go ahead and tag it Linq, too ;-)

Comment: Do you mean this     _context.Products.Where(p=>products.Contains(p.ProdID))? or you mean how to use Raw Sql?

Answer (score 33):

As per the comments on the question, the way you do this in EF Core is the same as for LINQ-to-SQL: use the `Enumerable.Contains` extension method on an array in your `Where` expression.

```cs
public async Task<List<Product>> GetProducts(params int[] ids)
{
    return await context.Products
        .Where(p => ids.Contains(p.ProdID)) // Enumerable.Contains extension method
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

[See related LINQ to Entities question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857973/linq-to-entities-sql-in-clause?noredirect=1&lq=1)