# Getting all Data from SQL using LINQ with comma-separated IDs

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, lambda, webapi

I do have a string of Empids separated by comma like:

`EMpID:"2007,2008,2002,1992,1000,2108,1085`

and I need to retrieve the records of all those specified employees using LINQ query.
I tried it with looping but I need to get that in efficient and faster way.

Here goes what i did using looping.

```
string[] EMpID_str = LeaveDictionary["EMpID"].ToString().Split(',');

for (int i = 0; i < EMpID_str.Length; i++)
            {
                EMpID = Convert.ToInt32(EMpID_str[i]);

               //Linq to get data for each Empid goes here
             }
```

But What I need is to use single LINQ or Lambda query to retrieve the same.Without looping

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show some example code you already have - this can help streamline other members of the site to answer you fast.

Comment: First convert your ,(comma) separated empId to string array like `var empArr = EmpId.split(',');` `var employeesResult = emplyeeList.Where(x => empArr.contains(x.EmpId.ToString()));`

Comment: @Rafalon Yes Can you give more details regarding the same.

Comment: @Rajeev arrays dont have `contains`

Comment: @MichaelSchönbauer isn't there a Linq extension for arrays which allows us to use `Contains` then? The accepted solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857973/linq-to-entities-sql-in-clause) seems to use `Contains` on arrays

Comment: @MichaelSchönbauer, I have used Contains on an array with LINQ many times in my code. You can check again.

Comment: @RajeevKumar,Thanks a lot Rajeev , It worked as expected !!

Comment: @Ne2, You are most welcome! Please vote for my comment as useful.

Comment: @RajeevKumar can you please post it as an answer here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert your ,(comma) separated empId to string array like below:

```
var empArr = EmpId.split(','); 
var employeesResult = emplyeeList.Where(x => empArr.contains(x.EmpId.ToString()));
```

I hope, it will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

If the Ids that you want to fetch are numbers, not strings, then you should not convert the string to an array of strings, but to a sequence of numbers:

```
IEnumerable<int> employeeIdsToFetch = LeaveDictionary["EMpID"].ToString()
    .Split(',')
    .Select(splitText => Int32.Parse(splitText));
```

To fetch all employees with thees Ids:

```
var fetchedEmployees = dbContext.Employees
    .Where(employee => employeeIdsToFetch.Contains(employee.Id))
    .Select(employee => new
    {
         // Select only the employee properties that you plan to use:
         Id = employee.Id,
         Name = employee.Name,
         ...
    });
```

Comment: Thank you @Harald for your help and suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression-1?view=netcore-3.1) class to build a `Func<int, bool>` from your string and use it with the `Where` methode:

```cs
var str = "2,5,8,9,4,6,7";

var para = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int));

var body = str.Split(",")
    .Select(s => int.Parse(s))
    .Select(i => Expression.Constant(i))
    .Select(c => Expression.Equal(para, c))
    .Aggregate((a, b) => Expression.Or(a, b));

Func<int, bool> func = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, bool>>(body, para).Compile();
```

and if you this solution to work with linq to SQL just dont compile the expression at the end and let the linq to SQL engine compile it to an efficent SQL expression.

Instead of the `Aggregate` Method (which will produce an expression with linear complexity) one could use an divide and conquer approach to fold the values into one value.

For example with this class:

```cs
public static class Helper
{
    public static T EfficientFold<T>(this List<T> list, Func<T, T, T> func)
    {
        return EfficientFold(list, 0, list.Count, func);
    }

    private static T EfficientFold<T>(List<T> list, int lowerbound, int upperbound, Func<T, T, T> func)
    {
        int diff = upperbound - lowerbound;
        var mid = lowerbound + diff / 2;

        if (diff < 1)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        else if (diff == 1)
        {
            return list[lowerbound];
        }
        else
        {
            var left = EfficientFold(list, lowerbound, mid, func);
            var right = EfficientFold(list, mid, upperbound, func);

            return func(left, right);
        }
    }
}
```

and then we can do

```
var body = str.Split(",")
    .Select(s => int.Parse(s))
    .Select(i => Expression.Constant(i))
    .Select(c => Expression.Equal(para, c))
    .ToList()
    .EfficientFold((a, b) => Expression.Or(a, b));
```

which gives the evaluation a complexity of `log(n)`.