# Filters not working in my repository in ASP.NET Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, filter

I have these parameters in a class:

```
public class UserParams
{
    public string Gender {get; set;}
    public int MinAge {get; set;} = 1;
    public int MaxAge {get; set;} = 19;
}
```

The query is done in the repository as shown below. First is to query for the child sex or gender and the second is to query for the child sex or gender

```
var query =  _context.Children.AsQueryable();
query = query.Where(c => c.Sex == userParams.Gender);

var minchildDob = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-userParams.MaxAge - 1);
var maxchildDob = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-userParams.MinAge);

query = query.Where(u => u.DateOfBirth >= minchildDob && u.DateOfBirth <= maxchildDob);
return await PagedList<Child>.CreateAsync(query.AsNoTracking(), userParams.PageNumber, userParams.PageSize);
```

The gender filter returns empty array of children and the minchildDob and maxchildDob too not working

Comment: You will need to provide more information other than "not working". What are the values coming into your userParams instance during this call? If the values are not correct then your calling code is likely not passing them correctly.

Comment: Does the second line (where you query by gender) produce any records? If not, you either don't have matching data, or there's something wrong with your `userParams.Gender` value relative to the data in your repository.  If it **does** return data, the problem is with the second `Where` clause, and you need to inspect those parameters.

Comment: the userparam.gender return empty array, i think its  is not initialise with value. when i initalise the userparam.gender = "Male", it returns the male only.. how do i get the female too.. i try this : if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(userParams.Gender)) { userParams.Gender == "Male" ? "Female" : "Male"; } in the get method but i get the error (Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement [API])

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @KingGenius I've updated my post

Comment: @KingGenius Did you get any progress sir? If my post is helpful to you, could you pls accept it as the answer? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(temp.Gender))
{
    all = all.Where(u => new[] { "men", "women" }.Contains(u.sex));
    //all = all.Where(t => t.sex == temp.Gender);
}
```

=======================Update=======================

```
 var temp = new UserParams();
    temp.Gender = "men";
    var minchildDob = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-temp.MaxAge - 1);
    var maxchildDob = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-temp.MinAge);
    
    IEnumerable<Table> all = from m in _context.data
                                        select m;
    _logger.LogError("all data");
    foreach (var item in all)
    {
         _logger.LogError(item.name);
    }
                _logger.LogError("============================================");
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(temp.Gender)) { 
         all = all.Where(t => t.sex == temp.Gender);
    }
    _logger.LogError("filter gender");
    foreach (var item in all) {
         _logger.LogError(item.name);
    }
                _logger.LogError("============================================");
    if (temp.MaxAge >　0) {
         all = all.Where(t => t.birthday >= minchildDob && t.birthday <= maxchildDob);
    }
    _logger.LogError("filter age");
    foreach (var item in all)
    {
        _logger.LogError(item.name);
    }
                _logger.LogError("============================================");
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for great dubbing.. when i initalise the userparam.gender = "Male", it returns the male only.. how do i get the female too.. i try  this : if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(userParams.Gender))
              {
                  userParams.Gender == "Male" ? "Female" : "Male";
              }
              in the get method but i get the error (Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement [API])

Comment: i initialised userparam.gender = "male" so query = query.Where(c => c.Sex == userParams.Gender); returns the male list and switch to the female in the get method with (  if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(userParams.Gender))
              {
                  userParams.Gender = userParams.Gender=="Female" ? "Male" : "Female";
              }
              ) but i want to get all the list of children before apply male or female filter per the user request

Comment: You mean, you wanna realize a filter like "all children in your database that have sex with male or female" ? Could you pls tell me your requirement vividly? I'm sorry for can't understand yours exactly.

Comment: public class UserParams
{
    public string Gender {get; set;} ="male"
    public int MinAge {get; set;} = 1;
    public int MaxAge {get; set;} = 19;
}                           the query [query = query.Where(c => c.Sex == userParams.Gender]);  select only male children when the list of all children is called, without the user selecting the male sex to filter. i want the male or female  children to be called only when the user filters sex by 'male' or 'female'

Comment: thanks alot for the assistance, i really appreciate  @Tiny Wang, ***i am also  looking  at something like this** {temp.mGender = "men", temp.fGender = "female", if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(temp.Gender)) { all = all.Where(t => t.sex == temp.mGender  || t.sex ==temp.fGender)};

Comment: Ok, I think you'd like to use the feature like 'in' in T-sql. I've updated my post. And you can also refer to this [high vote answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/857973) to see more details.

Comment: Great i will try that